# ReactJS Calling Other Compoent in if-else conditional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-4

I am new to ReactJS, and I am trying to build a simple web app to start. I have create two components: 1.Menu.jsx 2.ImgUrl.jsx. I want user click the menu button in Menu Component, and then triggering ImgUrl Component. While I am testing, however, the ImgUrl Component will show up and disappear immediately. Can anyone give me some suggestions what the best practices are? Thank you so much. Here are the codes:

```
import React from 'react';
import ImgUrl from './ImgUrl';
import { Button, Grid, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

var $=require('jquery');

export default class Menu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ' '};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleOption = this.handleOption.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(val) {
        this.setState({value: val});
        //console.log(val);
        this.handleOption(val);
      }

      handleOption(val){
        if(val=='ads'){
          //console.log(val);
          $.get(window.location.href + 'Xxx', (data) => {  
            //console.log(data);     
            this.setState({value: data}); 
          });

        }

      }

      render() {
        const token = this.state.value;
        console.log(token);
        let test;
        if (token == 'ads'){
          test = <ImgUrl/>;
        }
        return (
            <Col>
              <ul>
                <li onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this,"ads")} >Import Ads Weekly Report</li>
                <li onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this,"bs")} >Import BS Weekly Report</li>
                <li onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this,'adskpi')}>Import Ads KPI Report</li>
                <li onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this,'importkpi')}>Build Ads Market Report</li>
                <li onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this,'adsMarket')}>Build Non Ads KPI Report</li>
                <li onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this,'nonAdsMarket')}>Build Non Ads Market Report</li>
              </ul>
              <h2 class="selectOption">You just select: {this.state.value}</h2>
              <div class="select-folder"> 

                    {test}
              </div>
            </Col>
        );
      }
}
```

Comment: are you not getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't see any errors :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the output of the console.log(data) in your handleOption?

It might be that your handleOption sets the value in your state to something different than 'ads'. It will cause a re-render of  < Menu/> and you only display the < ImgUrl/> if value == 'ads', therefore it disappears.

Comment: console.log('val') return "ads"
console.log("data") will return the testing msg from my backend.
I am also thinking about the Menu will re-render, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: thats the problem. in handleOption the this.setState({value: data});  overrides the 'ads' previously written to value in your handleChange with the message from backend. maybe you want so save the message in a message attribute and dont override the value attribute?

Comment: sweet!!! Problem solved. I forget the this.state.value will be overrided. Now I set another state to solve the issue. Thank you so much! Welcome to Be a Contributor in Stackoverflow!